# Windows search which OCR's images and pdfs with text in them

Tags: windows, ocr, search

I often have scanned PDFs or JPEGs etc. which may have some text in them. One good example is screenshots that I take with screenshot captor.

Is there a way to make the Windows search "smart" so that it will search in these PDFs etc. which are image files with text in it (i.e. OCR them while indexing).

Alternatively any third party tools that will accomplish this?

I know I can use PDF Architect etc. to OCR a PDF but that would need manual intervention.